# How to create characters map for Khmer Unicode in FPDF?

Tags: fpdf, southeast-asian-languages

I want to create the characters map for Khmer Unicode in FPDF like other Unicode, so my Khmer Unicode will be supported in FPDF.But I don't know how. Here is the link to my Unicode characters: http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_1780.html#1780.

Please kindly help me. Thanks.

I hope you don't mind with my English.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26082046/1922144

Comment: Hi Bro Sophy SEM, have you found solution to add Khmer Font to FPDF? I am also looking for this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following URL to convert:

- http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/
- http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf

But Khmer unicode is not supported by FPDF, you can display Khmer unicode after convert but not with leg, meant can't render well with it. Might be you need to use PDFLib but might need to pay.

**Update 10/10/2020**: It works, read this: https://ask.osify.com/qa/11677

Comment: Read another case, I explained here, you can use the font to see if it's OK: https://ask.osify.com/qa/11677

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the previous answer, Khmer text will not be correctly rendered for 2 reasons :

- Some subscripts will be displayed at the right side of letters (not under the letter).
- Sometimes the order of Khmer Unicode is different than the order of display/pronunciation.

You will face the same problems with other PDF libraries (EzPDF or TCPDF for example). For my project, I chose to create a docx document instead of a PDF document. You'd need to code a lot of things in order to add the support of khmer language in a PDF library...

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendation.

Comment: You might need to read this: https://ask.osify.com/qa/11677 somehow I can make pdf report with it.