# Alternative web-font to render Khmer

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts, font-family, southeast-asian-languages

What is web-fonts (preferably available from Google Fonts) supports Khmer UI.

I have tried to define `font-family:khmer ui;` but it does not render even though I have the font installed on my computer.

Comment: I've made a new tag relevant to your question: [tag:southeast-asian-languages]. But I'm not sure which of your current tags to jettison to make space for it.

Answer (score 3):

Khmer (Cambodian) is pretty poorly supported but there is a convenient option which is as simple as Google Web Fonts.  There is in fact a Google Web Font that works.. see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcondrey/bL552Lyw/)

Google has a little known resource called [Early Access fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess) which is accessible from the "More scripts" hyperlink on the upper right side of the page on the typical Google Fonts webpage.  Currently available in the Early Access resource are fonts for Hebrew, Arabic, Lao, Ethiopic, Tamil, Thai, Korean, Bengali, Hindi, Myanmar, Armenian, Cherokee, Georgian, Gujarati, Gurmukhi, Japanese, Kannada, **Khmer**, Malayalam, Osmanya, Telugu, Chinese (traditional)

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Suwannaphum">
<p style="font-family: Suwannaphum,DaunPenh,Code2000;font-size:130%;">ខ្ញុំអាចញ៉ាំកញ្ចក់បាន ដោយគ្មានបញ្ហា</p>
```

[image]

### Further:

- [Google Web Fonts Early Access Discussion Board](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/early-access-fonts)

Comment: Khmer script is fully supported by Google Fonts (although khmer glyphs are included into few fonts) and by Google noto project. There is also the KhmerOS project from the Open Initiative that provides many fonts. You edited the post by changing the meaning of the original question. The "Khmer UI" doesn't mean "Khmer User Interface", but it was related to "Khmer UI" font name which is a licensed TrueType Font edited by Microsoft (see http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=373). And the OP wanted an alternative to this font.

Answer (score 2):

Add this link to your page:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khmer' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then apply the style for any element you want:

```
font-family: 'Khmer', cursive;
```

For more info take a look here: [https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Khmer](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aKhmer)

Answer (score 1):

The font "Khmer UI" (as mentionned into the original post) doesn't exist in the Google font collection. If you want to find what is the nearest font, go the the [Google fonts website](https://www.google.com/fonts). In the left sidebar, select Khmer into Script field. The Google fonts displaying Khmer characters will be listed.

[image: Select a font in Google fonts]

You cannot embed a font that is not installed on the computer where your website is used (the user/browser needs to install it prior using it). As stated into another answer you need to link to the place where your users can download the font (Google font API or your webserver). Otherwise, the browser used to display your website will use a default font.

For example, if you have selected the first font nammed "Hanuman", you need to add this link into your HTML code :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanuman' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And to apply the style wherever you want to use the font. All you need to do is add the font name to your CSS styles. For example:

```
font-family: 'Hanuman', serif;
```

Another great Google project is the [noto font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#/) : a font that will contains all known Unicode characters.

Remember that few fonts contain the Khmer letters.