# Google Khmer font shows only the square boxes

Tags: html, fonts, apk

I try to create a WebApp with Phonegap.

When I write Khmer `(កើត​អាប់​ស)` it works in Firefox and Chrome. But when I create the App (apk) my Smartphone only shows square boxes. But why?

I use this special font from Google
https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Khmer

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: Try this font I used in my answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26082046/1922144

Answer (score 1):

Details are available here which outline how to resolve the issue:

http://osify.com/2012/02/install-khmer-font-on-galaxy-s2-without-rooting-system/

To apply for Android 2.3.x:

1. Enable “unknown sources” installation (via Setting->Application)
2. Install Khmer.apk
3. Change font style
4. Settings > Display > Screen display > Font style
5. Choose Khmer
6. Restart the phone
7. Testing: Go to this website page: http://khnews.info/testing.html
8. To write Khmer, download Khmer keyboard from Android Market: Phum Keyboard or MultiLing Keyboard
   9) To enable input keyboard:

   - Settings > Languages and keyboard > Select input method
   - Choose: Phum Keyboard (in my case)
   - After you should be able to see everything in Khmer even though the rendering is not fine, you can type Khmer Unicode as well.

Further details: http://adkhmer.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=19:install-khmer-unicode-for-android-without-root&catid=6:android&Itemid=18

> FlipFont is a great technology from Monotype Imaging and it is using
>   in android phone of Samsung. The technology allows creating
>   application for adding more fonts into android phone beside the fonts
>   were shipped in system of the phone already.
>
> Unfortunately, from Android 4.0 (ICS) and earlier version, FlipFont
>   doesn't work with web browser, but it still find some more useful for
>   Khmer, especially in Galaxy Note II with Android 4.1.1 (Jelly Bean)
>   for browsing song title, video name in Khmer in youtube and chat with
>   friend via facebook messenger.
>
> I would like to note that it works with facebook messenger found on
>   Play Store only, it doens't work with facebook application yet. For
>   facebook application on Google Play Store, we also can chat in Khmer,
>   but we can’t read the feed post on the wall yet.
>
> In Android 4.1.1, Khmer rendering work perfectly in all part of
>   Android OS, but there are not font in system yet. So if you install
>   Khmer.apk in Galaxy Note II, you can read and write Khmer in many
>   applications without root the device.

---

Otherwise, if I were coding a webpage and trying to get the font to display on someone's phone .. If modiX is correct I would use FontForge or any other font editor to import the glyphs from the original font into a new font file and reassign the glyphs to a unicode range within the limits of Android's range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Android does not support those UTF8 ranges, however you could root the device to get the necessary character set on the device.

I found an app that claims to do the same without root: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.androidsanctum.kui
There are also direct APK installers on the web.